# Jest "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" associated with mui-color-input and CRA

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, create-react-app

I recently incorporated the `mui-color-input` library to my `create-react-app` project.  The project builds correctly but I am running into an error with the component test.

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

node_modules/mui-color-input/dist/mui-color-input.es.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { jsx as c, jsxs as lt, Fragment as Mt } from "react/jsx-runtime";
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 26 | import { MuiColorInput } from "mui-color-input";
         | ^
      27 |
```

Here is the dependency list in the `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.3",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.140",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.5",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.14.5",
    "mui-color-input": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.1",
    "jest-junit": "^10.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0",
    "typescript": "4.4.2"
  },
```

I have looked at other posts associated with this type of error but it usually has to do with an incorrect import statement. Based on the library [documentation](https://viclafouch.github.io/mui-color-input/docs/getting-started/), my import seems to be correct.

My initial thought was that a testing library was possibly outdated and causing the issue but this error only applies to this particular import statement within the entire app and after updating certain packages such as the `@testing-library/react`, the error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with mui-one-time-password-input and I solved it by changing the version of the library to an older one